# How to add another parameters to WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query

I need to do something like that:

```
        $postsOrder = get_sub_field('posts-ordering');

        if ($postsOrder = 'post_views_count') {
            $queryPopular = array (
                'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            );
        }

        $query = new WP_Query(
            array(
            'posts_per_page' => $postsCount,
            'post_type' => $postsType->name,
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'orderby' => $postsOrder,
            'taxonomy' => $postsTaxonomy,
            $queryPopular
            ),
        );
```

The point is that if $postsOrder is equal 'post_views_count', then in $query should be added two another parameters. How to do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$postsOrder = get_sub_field('posts-ordering');

```
    if ($postsOrder = 'post_views_count') {
        $queryPopular = array (
            'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        );
    }

    $query = new WP_Query(
        array(
        'posts_per_page' => $postsCount,
        'post_type' => $postsType->name,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => $postsOrder,
        'taxonomy' => $postsTaxonomy,
        $queryPopular
        ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to add other two parameter as condition.

```
  $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => $postsCount,
      'post_type' => $postsType->name,
      'order' => 'DESC',
      'orderby' => $postsOrder,
      'taxonomy' => $postsTaxonomy,
  );

  $postsOrder = get_sub_field('posts-ordering');

  if ($postsOrder == 'post_views_count') {
      $args['meta_key'] = 'post_views_count';
      $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
  }
  $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Can somebody tell me whats wrong in above code ? why answer was downvoted ?

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it soon :) Don't worry about downvoted answer, there is a lot of strange behaviors on Stack ;)